# seventeen tiles on a torus

Tags: combinatorics

The torus $\mathbb{R}^2 \mod((4,1),(1,-4))$ has area 17.  Can it be covered by seventeen labelled tiles in two different ways so that any pair of tiles is neighbours of each other (at an edge or a vertex) in one of the two patterns?

Comment: What restrictions are there on the tiles? Their shapes? Do they need to all have the same area? Also is there any difference in this problem if we omit the torus and just start with a square of side length $\sqrt{17}$? Maybe the tiles are to be aligned with the axes in $\mathbb{R^2}$. In sum question needs more specifics. (otherwise put a $K_{17}$ inside and fatten up the vertices into regions, call them tiles)

Comment: I was thinking of unit squares aligned with the $x,y$ axes.  Then each square has eight neighbours as in a chessboard.  In two patterns, it has sixteen neighbours, so with 17 squares it has every other square as a neighbour once.

Comment: So then the thing to try is to find a labeling of the tiles in the second pattern  such that if two squares in the first pattern are *not* neighbors then they *are* neighbors in the second. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, it followed on, in a way, from my earlier question about diners.

Comment: This is a great question!  It can be generalized to $n$-fold labelings of any torus where $8n+1$ is a sum of two squares; the problem is trivial for $n=1$ and $n=4$ doesn't satisfy the conditions, but $n=3$ lets the question be asked of both the torus 'generated by' $\langle 5,0\rangle$ (i.e., a $5x5$ square with sides identified) as well as the torus generated by $\langle3,4\rangle$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, I have a bounty open this week on this problem  - Zn∖{0} splits into octets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the generating translations as $(4,1),(-1,4)$ we see we have a square lattice tipped a bit from the axes. Note we can also move by $(-4,-1),(1,-4).$ We need a complete and nonredundant list of the translates of the (axes aligned) unit squares under the translation group. Label initially each unit square by the coordinates of its lower left corner. Then a nonredundant list is
$$(-1,3),\ (0,3),\ (1,3),\ (2,3),\  (3,3),\\
(0,2),\ (1,2),\ (2,2),\ (3,2),\\
(0,1),\ (1,1),\ (2,1),\ (3,1),\\
(0,0),\ (1,0),\ (2,0),\ (3,0).$$
Note that geometrically these unit squares make up a region consisting of a $4\times 4$ square with an extra unit square stuck on to its upper left, flush with the top of the big square. These shapes then tile the plane, as a drawing shows. The generators of the transformations of the group serve to move these shapes around to achieve the tiling.

Now for ease of reference relabel these as the integer sequence $1,2,\cdots,17$ going across the rows one by one, so that e.g. $(-1,3)$ gets the new name $1$, and to take another random case $(1,2)$ becomes $7.$

In terms of these numeric labels, regarded mod 17, the point $x$ and its neighbors are the nine points
$$x+12,x+13,x+14,\\ x+16,x,x+1,\\x+3,x+4,x+5.$$
These formulas come from using the translations of the group to see which identified unit squares end up bordering a fixed one of them, and the above arrangement is in the shape of the $9 \times 9$ square containing the particular unit square $x$ being looked at.

The list of addends in these formulas (for the neighbors of $x$) is the following subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{17}^*:$
$$A=\{1,3,4,5,12,13,14,16\}.$$
Note that when  $A$ is mapped by $f(x)=2x$ (mod $17$), its image is the complement of $A$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}^*$. It follows that if we take the map $f(x)=2x$ (mod $17$) and apply it to the labels in the "first tiling" $T_1$ above, we obtain a distinct (ordered) tiling $T_2$ and two numbered tiles touch (at corner or edge) in $T_1$ if and only if they do *not* touch in $T_2$.

Comment: The diners problem looked interesting. Would you be interested in "torus-izing" it, i.e. in regarding the two at one end as neighbors of the two at the other end? In that case an approach like the above might work, since one would get symmetric sets for neighbors.

Comment: I suppose so.  I stopped the computer after a while with nine people on either side because my algorithm was going to take a long time to go through all the possibilities.  And the proof that fewer than eight on each side is impossible holds all the more so for the torussed version.

Answer (score 3):

I've done an exhaustive search for solutions.  I'll start with labels as follows:

```
 0
 1, 2, 3, 4
 5, 6, 7, 8
 9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16
```

(So this is immediately slightly different from coffeemath's solution, which I don't understand.)  If we constrain the solution to have 0 in the same position, there are 4 solutions, closely related to each other:

Solution S0:

```
 0,
 5, 7, 1, 3,
13,15, 9,11,
 6, 8, 2, 4,
14,16,10,12
```

Solution S1:

```
 0,
 3,11, 4,12,
 1, 9, 2,10,
 7,15, 8,16,
 5,13, 6,14
```

Solution S2:

```
 0,
14, 6,13, 5,
16, 8,15, 7,
10, 2, 9, 1,
12, 4,11, 3
```

Solution S3:

```
 0,
12,10,16,14,
 4, 2, 8, 6,
11, 9,15,13,
 3, 1, 7, 5
```

These solutions are in inverse pairs: S0-S1 and S2-S3.

All these solutions are isohedral, in the sense that we can specify a relationship between pairs of labels before and after.  For example:

S0: Let x be a label, and y be the label immediately lower than it in the original layout.  In S0, place y two squares LEFT OF x.

This is enough to define the solution.  For S1, S2 and S3, replace 'LEFT OF' with 'BELOW', 'ABOVE' and 'RIGHT OF' respectively.  We can regard S0-S1 and S2-S3 as reflections of each other in the x-y diagonal.

As I mentioned, there are no solutions except this collection of 4 solutions (up to translations of the tiling).